# lexical_cast int to string

Tags: c++, boost, lexical-cast

Is it safe to ignore exception of [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) when converting `int` to `std::string`?

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore"?

Comment: I don't see why this cast can fail, therefore I want to perform cast without catching bad_lexical_cast

Comment: You should ALWAYS wrap calls that can throw in try, catch blocks.

Comment: @Konrad Remarkably bad advice.

Comment: @Konrad:  Partly it depends on what you consider "wrap".  There should be a try/catch block at the appropriate level to handle the exception, except sometimes in debug mode when you just want it to show on the debugger.  This isn't necessarily anywhere near where the exception is thrown.  In this case, I don't think `boost::lexical_cast` can throw anything besides `bad_alloc`, and normally there's nothing to do about that locally.  Usually you'd catch it only to provide a reasonable message for end users.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737328/why-should-i-not-wrap-every-block-in-try-catch

Comment: How about some of the examples from the following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx They are very efficient and somewhat elegant - they don't throw exceptions but rather return a bool indicating a success or failure.

Comment: ^ Here I was thinking a major reason for exceptions was to avoid reliance upon return codes. What if those functions needed to return other, actually useful (i.e. non-exceptional) values?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Exception raised by lexical cast when converting an `int` to `std::string` are not associated to the conversion, but to resource unavailable. So you can ignore this in the same way you ignore the exception `bad_alloc` raised by operator new.

Comment: Note that I said as the poster "when converting an int to std::string"

Answer (score 6):

As you say, I don't believe the cast can fail for the numerical types for conversion reasons - it can still fail because the string cannot be allocated, of course, but people don't normally catch that error except at the highest level of their code.

Answer (score 0):

If you "ignore" an exception it will propagate back up the call stack until it is caught elsewhere, or it terminates the program, the point being you *can* safely not catch exceptions without worrying about you program continuing and doing unsafe/unknown things (as long as a "crash" to command prompt is acceptable error behaviour or you have some other way of dealing with unknown exceptions).

Unfortunately exception stack traces aren't so easy to get in C++, so creating useful error messages when exceptions aren't caught locally isn't always easy.