# Should I always wrap code in Try Catch blocks for Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've neglected exception handling long enough, mainly because I never see it used in the snippets I see on SO, 2 years writing javascript and I didn't even know javascript had exception handling. Other languages it is very common to see exception handling, is exception handling less important to javascript? What are some typical scenarios one should always use exception handling in javascript and shouldn't?

Does this rule apply for javascript too?

[Why should I not wrap every block in "try"-"catch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737328/why-should-i-not-wrap-every-block-in-try-catch)

Comment: Let's suppose you did wrap every block in a try/catch: what would your catch block actually do with the exceptions?

Comment: @nnnnnn wouldn't avoiding crashing the whole script be useful enough? I see some try catch blocks in jQuery UI' code with catch blocks, so I assume that's one purpose for wrapping all code?

Comment: My point is to think about what will happen or should happen after the exception and be sure to code accordingly. "Avoiding crashing the whole script" doesn't really help if an exception happens in the first half but the second half won't work without valid results from the first half. And some exceptions can be completely avoided by coding correctly in the first place - I'm not saying you would do this, but I've seen lots of code where the author wrote dodgy code and then wrapped it in a try with an empty catch block just to avoid letting the user see avoidable errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common strategy in javascript is to write defensively and test thoroughly.

e.g. there are libraries that start at square one with test similar to:

```
var element;

if (document && document.getElementById) {
  element = document.getElementById('foo');
}

if (element) {
  // use element
}
```

but written in a more generic format with tests like *isHostMethod*.

Employ try..catch only as a last resort where feature detection or other defences aren't available. Testing host objects sometimes returns useless results or may even throw errors (e.g. all XMLHttpRequest scripts use try..catch because testing for support in IE is inconclusive so the only option is to just call it and see what happens).

Minor script errors aren't much of an issue as most browsers won't show them by default. Most non–trivial pages throw errors all the time (including SO) depending on things like the browser, settings and user's network environment. Users are just denied functionality that they may or may not be aware they are missing (and may actually benefit from). Hence a typical strategy is to make we pages functional without any script, then add script features to enhance usability. That way there is always a fallback to basic functionality if an error occurs that might otherwise prevent the page being useful.

This strategy may not always be possible, but it's a good starting point and should not be abandoned lightly.

Answer (score 1):

In C it was good practice to always check the return code.

Then comes the C++ with exceptions. An the Java has made really heavy usage of them, even too heavy (for example: `Integer.parseInt` : even if you only want to check, if something is String, you must still handle exception).

JavaScript has other concept of exception handling. A good practice is to provide a **callback** for exception handling. jQuery selectors still 'work' if no element is found, you get only 0-element selector.

So if you are using code that throws exceptions, you must handle it. But you should avoid throwing exceptions and support error handling via callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Exception are a big problem if the case is performance. But it make error detection in very easy way.

If are using someones tools that throw exception then you should run them through `try catch` block.

Try to minimize throwing exception when coding javascript