# C++ how to write something into a logfile just before the programm crashes

Tags: c++, logging, crash

everyone, i tried finding a solution on the internet, yet i've failed and i need your help.

I need to write a programm which has the following property:

If it crashes - it should write the time of the crash and the line, where it occured.

I've made a special logging function for this purpose, however - i have no idea how to intercept the crash event and make it write to the logfile - just after the crash occured.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Does [how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes) help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [std::uncaught_exception](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/uncaught_exception/) in your destructor to check if the stack is unwinding because of an exception and if it's the case write a scoped log entry.

There may also be some interesting information for you in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2737554/2573221). It contains a lot of useful information about good and bad practice when it comes down to exception handling.

Comment: Use **cppreference** instead of cplusplus

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to implement it.

Let me explain exactly what your trying to catch on a crash.

These are called unhandled exceptions. These are read passed the C++ exception handlers and are considered OS level exception handling. This means your implementation of where and how you catch your errors is OS dependent. (very important)

I only know windows so.... here is the ways you can do it in the windows platform.

three ways.

- __try __except -- basically like try catch but lower level
- catching signals -- google this if you want there pretty useless in my opinion not going to even bother explaining
- my recommend solution is

  [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/postmortem-debugging/185300443?pgno=1)