# value isDefinedAt is not a member of play.api.mvc.SimpleResult

Tags: scala, playframework, try-catch, scala-2.10, playframework-2.2

the following code is giving error, and i dont know whats the reason, and how remove this error, tell me what i am doing wrong.

```
def members(id:String,name:String) = Action { implicit request =>
    try{
        session.get("userId").map{user=>
            val Data =NewModel.getInfo(id)
            val userId=session.get("userId").get
            if(userId==Data.createdBy){
                Ok(html.groupMembers(Data,"mainAdmin"))
            }else{try{
                    val admin=NewModel.admin(id,userId);
                        Ok(html.members(Data,"subAdmin"))
                 }catch{
                        try{
                            val member=NewModel.member(id,userId)
                                Ok(html.members(Data,"member"));
                        }catch{
                          if(Data.privacy!="secret")
                            Ok(html.members(Data,"outsider"))
                          else
                            Ok(html.noPageFound())
                        }
                 }   
            }   
        }.getOrElse{
            Redirect("/")
        }
    }catch{
        case e=>
          println(e)
          Ok(html.onError())
    }
    }//end groupSetting
```

Comment: That's the compiler telling you that you're using the wrong syntax in your `catch` blocks. But please, for everyone's sake, don't use exceptions for flow control at all.

Comment: @millhouse val admin=NewModel.admin(id,userId);
giving exception when its not found the value.
i am using cassandra at backend

Comment: @flavian this is scala code (of controller).
i want to send subAdmin a string when he is a admin, cassandra gives null pointer exception if it doesnt found the colum value.
so i uses try catch.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is so simple

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use this in every catch block

```
catch{
    case e=>
      //code
}
```

Edit:

```
catch{
    case e:Exception=>
      //code
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that a `catch-all` *catch* statement is usually bad practice - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2737554/409976

Comment: Also, @Amit, I got this `warning` when using your `catch-all` approach - `This catches all Throwables. If this is really intended, use `case e : Throwable` to clear this warning.`