# Creating reusable promises without .catch

Tags: javascript

I am working in a new codebase that has a pattern where some reusable functions return a promise from a chain, but they don't handle errors.

Here is an example:

```
function createScheduleForGroup(group) {
  if (notInProduction()) {
    group.gschedScheduleId = '0';
    return Bluebird.resolve(group);
  }
// note: schedule is a global within the file
  return schedule.createSchedule(group.name).then(function (schedule) {
    group.gschedScheduleId = schedule.id;
    return group.save();
  });
}
```

In the example above, there isn't a `.catch` or a `reject` function passed to the `.then`.

The function is eventually used in an express route where the error is handled:

```
router.post('/schedule', function(req, res, next) {
       scheduleLogical
         .createScheduleGroup(req[config.entity])
         .then(function(group) {
           res.status(201).json(group);
         })
         .catch(next); 

// if creteScheduleGroup throws an error it is handled here
```

**Is it a common pattern to not define error handlers for a promise returned from a function, and anticipate whoever uses the function to attach the appropriate error handlers?**

To make this clearer for my own understanding, I made a simulation of this specific function and all the functions used within the promise chain. Here it is:

```js
function getScheduleMock() {
  // this promise promisifys an older api that uses callbacks
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // note this is simulating an api call:
    const response = Math.round(Math.random());
    // 0 === err, 1 === success

    if(response === 0) return reject(response);
    resolve(response);
    
  })
  // error hanlding :)
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    return Promise.reject(err);
    // there is an error handling function that logs the errors. If the error doesn't match expected errors, it rejects the error again as I have here.
  })
  .then(responseData => {
    return Promise.resolve(responseData);
  })
}

function createScheduleForGroupMock() {
  return getScheduleMock().then(responseData => Promise.resolve('everything worked :)'));
 // Note: group.save() from the original returns a promise
  // just like the actual example, the promise is returned
  // but there isn't any form of error handling except within the getScheduleMock function
}

createScheduleForGroupMock(); // when the error is rejected in the .catch() in getScheduleMock, the error is unhandled.

/* ***************** */


/* the createScheduleForGroup method is used within an express route which has error handling, here is an example of the code: */

// router.post('/schedule', function(req, res, next) {
//       scheduleLogical
//         .createScheduleGroup(req[config.entity])
//         .then(function(group) {
//           res.status(201).json(group);
//         })
//         .catch(next); 
        
// if creteScheduleGroup throws an error it is handled here
```

I'm fairly new to error handling promises and from what I've been reading and practicing, I generally felt you should always include an error handler. The codebase I'm working in has a lot of methods that use the pattern of `createScheduleForGroup` where there isn't an error handler defined in the function, but instead, it is handled and attached after the function is used.

Some of the functions used within `createScheduleForGroup` handle their own errors, and I'm confused and curious about the balance on when to handle errors in a function that returns a promise and when to attach them when you use the function.

Comment: Promise error handling isn't any different from conventional error handling, you should only `catch` when you can gracefully handle the error, in all other cases error handling should be deferred to the calling method.

Comment: I will also add that catch-log-rethrow is an anti-pattern. Ideally you would have the error bubble all the way up to a handler that logs errors before bringing down and restarting the application, or log the error when it is handled (if necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a common pattern to not define error handlers for a promise returned from a function, and expect whoever uses the function to attach the appropriate error handlers?

Yes, totally. It's not just "a common pattern", it's the absolute standard pattern.

Just like you don't put a `try`/`catch` statement in every synchronous function, you don't put a `.catch` callback on every promise that you return. In fact, it's [considered an antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896442/why-is-catcherr-console-errorerr-discouraged) to catch errors that you cannot handle.

Answer (score -1):

You can have an error handler in each function.

```
function aPromise() {

   return new Promise(function(resolver, reject){

      //Handle any error here and attach different information via your own errror class

   })

}

async function parentProcess() {

   try{
    await aPromise()
   }
   catch(e) {
       //Handle and attach more info here
   }
}

function grandParentProcess() {

   try{
     parentProcess();
   }
   catch(e){
       //Handle the error
   }

}
```

You don't essentially have to handle error in the parent function if the grand parent function handles it to avoid the `UnhandledPromiseRejection` error.

Comment: thanks! I think my main question is when working on a bigger codebase, is there a best practice when creating functions that return promises? I understand the exception can be handled if the grandparent function handles it, but what happens if there isn't a grandparent function?  

As you mentioned, there may be an `uncaughtExceptionHandler`, but it feels unnatural to me to depend on it, from my understanding it feels like the `uncaughExceptionHandler` is there in case an error is thrown that isn't handled. It's highly possibly my perception on this is 100% wrong.