# Getting "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value " while using Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, function

I've started using Firebase recently with my Unity game to create a simple turnbased game.
First time using Firebase functions as well, not to mention not that skilled in JS.

I'm using this code that handles a simple matchmaking system for newly added players to the matchmaking sub-database and match them with other players who are idle, then creates a random id for the game set it to them and then creates a new object in a "games" sub-database.

I've uploaded the core to Firebase and started testing it manually on the real-time database by adding "users" but it's not working and the log says :

**Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value**

I've looked online to find out what to do but I'm lost about "Promises"
I'd appreciate help in this matter.

Here's the JS code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const database = admin.database();

exports.matchmaker = functions.database.ref("matchmaking/{playerId}")
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const gameId = generateGameId();

      database.ref("matchmaking").once("value").then((players) => {
        let secondPlayer = null;
        players.forEach((player) => {
          if (player.val() == "searching" &&
          player.key !== context.params.playerId) {
            secondPlayer = player;
          }
        });

        if (secondPlayer === null) return null;

        database.ref("matchmaking").transaction(function(matchmaking) {
          if (matchmaking === null ||
            matchmaking[context.params.playerId] !== "" ||
            matchmaking[secondPlayer.key] !== "searching") {
            return matchmaking;
          }
          matchmaking[context.params.playerId] = gameId;
          matchmaking[secondPlayer.key] = gameId;
          return matchmaking;
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.snapshot.child(
              context.params.playerId).val() !== gameId) {
            return null;
          }
          const game = {
            gameInfo: {
              gameId: gameId,
              playersIds: [context.params.playerId, secondPlayer.key],
            },
            turn: context.params.playerId,
          };


          database.ref("games/" + gameId).set(game).then((snapshot) => {
            console.log("Game created successfully!");
            return null;
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });

          return null;
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });

        return null;
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    });
/**
 * Generates random game id
 * @return {int} Game id
 */
function generateGameId() {
  const possibleChars =
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  let gameId = "";
  for (let j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
    gameId +=
    possibleChars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleChars.length));
  }
  return gameId;
}
```

UPDATE:
I was able to fix it by adding a return value at the end of the onCreate method.

return context.

Comment: Does that error message have a line number? From where is it thrown?

Comment: Also, [don't write `.catch()` everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50896442/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi no Emulator log doesn't show but I figured it out.
and thank you for the catch advice.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding "return context" at the of the onCreate method.