# Type 'Promise<Hotel[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Hotel[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, promise, pouchdb

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70527115/populating-ionic-angular-list-with-pouchdb). I decided to rewrite my code with Promises, but how would I Promise an Array of interfaces without requiring all of the Array properties?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import PouchDB from 'node_modules/pouchdb';

interface Hotel {
    name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {
    hotels: any;
    item: Hotel[];

    constructor() {
        this.hotels = new PouchDB(<!-- db link -->, {
            auto_compaction: true
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() { this.item = this.ionViewWillEnter(); }
    ionViewWillEnter(): Promise<Hotel[]> {
        var promise = this.hotels.allDocs({
            include_docs: true
        }).then(function(result): Hotel[] {
            var data = result.rows.map(function(row): Hotel {
                return({name: row.doc.name});
            });
            return(data);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
        return(promise);
    }
}
```

```
Type 'Promise<Hotel[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Hotel[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
[ng] 23     ngOnInit() { this.item = this.ionViewWillEnter(); }
```

Comment: Avoid [`.catch(err => console.log(err))`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50896442/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ionViewWillEnter() returns a promise, not a value. So you have to start the promise and give it a callback either with then() or await.

```
  ngOnInit() { this.ionViewWillEnter().then(item => this.item = item); }
```

I recommend you read some of [this docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) regarding promises.