# Try/catch a promise or just catch?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

`this.$auth.loginWith` returns a promise, but I am unsure if I should wrap it in a try/catch or just use a `catch` on the promise.

Which is the correct way?

Try/Catch:

```
async login() {
            try {
                const response = await this.$auth.loginWith('laravelSanctum', {
                    data: {
                        email: 'xxx',
                        password: 'xxx',
                    },
                });

                this.$auth.setUser(response.data.data);
            } catch (e) {

            }
        },
```

Catch:

```
async login() {
                const response = await this.$auth.loginWith('laravelSanctum', {
                    data: {
                        email: 'xxx',
                        password: 'xxx',
                    },
                }).catch(function(e) {
                });

                this.$auth.setUser(response.data.data);
        },
```

Comment: What have you done so far to find an answer on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: These do two different things. They don't have to but the way you've written them, the first piece of code will *not* call `this.$auth.setUser();` on a failure. The second piece of code will assign `undefined` to `response` (since the `.catch()` doesn't return anything), and `this.$auth.setUser(response.data.data);` *will* be called. Then fail because `response` is `undefined`, thus `response.data` will throw an error.

Comment: Don't do either of these. Ignoring errors is not a good practice, if you really have a reason at least add a comment why this is intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's best practice **not** to combine `async`/`await` with using the promise methods (`.then`, `.catch`), so your `try`/`catch` would usually be the better of those two options.

And [@VLAZ put his finger on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70696187/try-catch-a-promise-or-just-catch/70696268#comment124978195_70696187) one of the good reasons for that: When you mix metaphors like that, it can be tricky to read the flow, and in your case the version using `.catch` will actually cause an error because the your specific `catch` handler converts rejection to fulfullment with `undefined`, so the code continues after the `await`, and tries to do `this.$auth.setUser(response.data.data);` when `response` is `undefined`, causing a new error that seems unrelated to login.

---

But normally, even better is to [not handle the rejection at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50896442/1048572) so that the caller knows whether the login worked or not (because `login` will reject if there was an error). But for entry points into your code (event handlers, that kind of thing), inline handling of rejections can have a place. It depends on how `login` is used. Other than entry points, default to letting the error/rejection propagate to the caller.