# Why can't try/catch handle error throw in Promise constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

This code get's `unhandledRejection` error and I don't know why.

If the Error is thrown in try/catch, shouldn't it be caught by Catch Expression?

```js
async function main () {
  try {
    await run(throwError)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('main catch error', error);
  }
}

async function run (callback) {
  return new Promise(async resolve => {
    await throwError()
  });
}

async function throwError () {
  throw new Error('custom error')
}

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  console.log('unhandledRejection - reason', reason, promise);
})

main()
```

Comment: Please note, `return new Promise` inside an async function is unneeded. Please remove it? Also there's no need to await `throwError()` - Making those changes seems to also fix your issue

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Try/catch a promise or just catch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70696187/try-catch-a-promise-or-just-catch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not caught because you're passing an `async` function into `new Promise`. An error inside an `async` function rejects the promise that the function returns. The `Promise` constructor doesn't do anything a promise returned by the function you pass it (the return value of that function is completely ignored), so the rejection goes unhandled. This is one of the promise anti-patterns: Don't provide a promise to something that won't handle it (like `addEventListener` on the web, or the `Promise` constructor, or `forEach`, ...).

Similarly, there's no reason to use `new Promise` in your `async` function at all. `async` functions *already* return promises. That's another anti-pattern, sometimes called the [explicit promise construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). (But see below if you're wrapping an old-fashioned callback API.)

If you remove the unnecessary `new Promise`, it works as you expect (I also updated `run` to call `callback` rather than ignoring it and calling `throwError` directly):

```
async function main() {
    try {
        await run(throwError);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("main catch error", error);
    }
}

async function run(callback) {
    return await callback();
}

async function throwError() {
    throw new Error("custom error");
}

process.on("unhandledRejection", (reason, promise) => {
    console.log("unhandledRejection - reason", reason, promise);
});

main();
```

---

About the `return await callback();` in that example: Because whatever you return from an `async` function is used to settle the function's promise (fulfilling it if you return a non-thenable, resolving it to the thenable if you return one), and that `return` is at the top level of the function (not inside a `try`/`catch` or similar), you *could* just write `return callback();`. In fact, you could even remove `async` from `run` and do that. But keeping the `await` makes the async stack trace clearer on some JavaScript engines, more clearly indicates what you're doing, and keeps working correctly even if someone comes along later and puts a `try`/`catch` around that code.

---

In a comment, you said that you used `new Promise` because you were wrapping around a callback-based API. Here's how you'd do that (see also the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/)):

```
// Assuming `callback` is a Node.js-style callback API, not an
// `async` function as in the question:
function run(callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        callback((err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**but**, you don't have to do that yourself if the callback-based API uses the standard Node.js convention as above, there's a [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal) function in `utils`.

Comment: This manual `new Promise()` call could have been done just for the sake of a generalized MRE.

Comment: @NathanWiles not necessary in *any* case. It's an `async` function.

Comment: It is necessary, because removing the `new Promise()` call does not reproduce the error. Keeping it in place was the minimum reproducible example of the issue this person was experiencing.

Comment: @NathanWiles - Maybe, though it's very misleading (and it's really common for folks not to understand `async` functions). The main point about the above, though, is: Don't pass an `async` function to `new Promise`, it doesn't do anything with the returned promise.

Comment: @NathanWiles - You're making an awfully large assumption there, and frankly the OP's `run` doesn't make sense even through that lens. The OP **already** has a promise (just like [the link calls out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)): The one from `throwError()`. There's no need whatsoever for `new Promise` in that code.

Comment: Thanks, this answer solved my problem.

As for why I use async/await in new Promise, it's because in the actual code, the function entry only supports callback style and not Promise, so I need to run the Promise in callback and call the actual function via async/await, get the result and return

Comment: @Lxxyx - In that situation, the function you'd pass to `new Promise` shouldn't be an `async` function (it should never be one); if it weren't `async`, you would have seen the error the way you expected to (because an error thrown inside the `new Promise` callback rejects the promise). And if the *only* thing the function was doing was wrapping that API, I'd suggest `run` itself probably shouldn't be `async` since you're explicitly creating a promise as in [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/) about wrapping callback-style APIs in promises. Happy coding! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to throw an error in this case, you want to invoke `reject`:

```js
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject('custom error')
  });
```

If the error being thrown is out of your control, you can catch it inside the promise implementation and reject in that case.