# Promise recursion with axios, retrying on catch

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm still quite new to Promises and would like some clarification.

For some context, I'm trying to get a file from an URL. The file is stored using IPFS and when there's a timeout I would like to try and call `axios.get()` again.

My current problem is, that it looks like the file is being downloaded but the function rarely returns anything, it looks like the download is super slow, however if I open the link directly I get the file instantly, making me think there's something wrong with my promises, even though no `then()` nor `catch()` is ran. My current code is as follows:

```js
const getIPFSMedia = (url) => {
  return axios.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).then((response) => {
    return URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
  }).catch((e) => {
    if (e.message === GET_IPFS_TIMED_OUT) {
      return getIPFSMedia(url);
    } else {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  });
}

const fetchData = async() => {
  const image = await getIPFSMedia(url); // Slow or rarely returns, but when it does it has my file in it
  console.log(image)
}
```

Comment: Hasn't the file been cached to be instantly retrieved?

Comment: @testing_22 yea for sure, however the axios.then() doesn't run even if I open a different tab and check the cached file

Comment: in the catch, shouldn't be `return e.message` instead?

Comment: @Alvin Indeed I should return something there!

Comment: @NoSarcasm No you shouldn't, you should re`throw` the error [if you can't handle it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50896442/1048572)

Comment: Why are you using `URL.createObjectURL`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plug-in for axios called [axios-retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-retry) which you can use:

```js
import axiosRetry from 'axios-retry';

axiosRetry(axios, { retries: 1 });

axios.get(url); // It will retry one time if the request fail.
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, but would still like to know if my promises have some problem that I'm unable to see

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the axios-retry plugin, it would be helpful if you increase the axios default timeout, in case it is not enough to read the file.

```js
instance.get('/yourRequestedURL', {
  timeout: 15000 //Try to give a little more than the timeout of the file
});
```